# How to use Ant design components with state variables of React class methods instead of React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I always use ant design with react hooks but the old code is written in react classes and it uses state variables and on page load state variables value changes async by API response and as React class methods implementation the UI is rerendered. 
Recently I added ant design Modal, Form components to one of the pages which were written using react class and I followed React hooks for new code but the Modal closes and opens automatically as well as Form filled values are cleared when async API response set the state variable value and it triggers UI rerendering.

How can I prevent the ant design Modal, Form to stop automatically close and open when state variable values are changed by the async API calls?

Comment: See the antd component's documentation and check if there are props to control the modal's visibility. You can't expect to get a working answer without posting any code.

Comment: All the components of ant design are rerendered on state variable value change which I want to prevent.  Modal has property visible={isVisible} which works fine but UI rerendering closes and opens modal automatically when state variable value is changed by async API response.